# Scanner hangs on user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am stuck and cannot figure out why my input Scanner hangs, waiting for new input. Can anyone see what I am missing or not doing? I know it's something stupid, thank you!

```
while (more == true){       
str = "";
val = "";

System.out.println("Enter a Constructor argument type : ");
try {
    str  = input.nextLine();
} catch (Exception e) {
    more = false; input.close();
}

if ( str.isEmpty() || str.equals("") || (str == null) ) {
more = false;
}
else{
    arguments.add(str);

    System.out.println("Enter it's value : ");
    try {
      val  = input.nextLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      more = false; 
    }
      if ( val.equals("") || (val == null) || val.isEmpty() ) {
        more = false;
      }
      else{
        values.add(val);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What input values make it hang?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29 Check this. You probably need to have a end sequence to tell scanner to stop looking ahead

Comment: they are both String values that I manipulate later.

Comment: I checked out "docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/…", but there is a carriage return when I enter no input (and wish to end the user input piece), which means it should end reading input.

Comment: As I read this, it accepts input until you give it an empty line, and then it moves on to your next step. Is this not what you want it to do? If not, please spell out what you were hoping to have happen.

Comment: It asks for and is given a value for "str" and "val" variables, then I hit return on the next input request with the intent of stopping the input to process the values (and get out of the loop with "more" == false, but the second time around, with a return as the input, it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

if ( str.isEmpty() || str.equals("") || (str == null) )

this line makes no sense. If you want to program defensively always first check if the object is null. Your line will throw a NPE if str is null instead of just setting the variable more to false.
My suggestion how to change this line:
if (str == null || str.isEmpty() || str.equals(""))
or just use
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(str))

The line "if ( val.equals("") || (val == null) || val.isEmpty() )" also can be replaced by just "if(StringUtils.isEmpty(val))" for the same reasons.

If you want to end the input in the console, try passing "Ctrl+Z" combination for EOF.

Comment: That line was emphasizing what I have tried. The "isEmpty doesn't work, as there is a value returned, but I can't seem to flag it with the \s or \n either.

Comment: Actually it does work. See documentation here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29
Also try breaking the input with Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Why don't any of these work? str.isEmpty(), str==null, str =="", opr checking fo ra \n or \b? It seems to me that the StringUtils is the same thing as what I was trying to do, but from a different angle.